# No Azure subscriptions discovered to provision app resources to

Tags: teams-toolkit

I'm using the VSC Teams Toolkit. But when I sign in to my Azure account to provision my files, it says "No subscriptions discovered" as shown below:

[image]

Which subscription should I get to proceed with provisioning the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. You really need to go to [portal.azure.com](https://portal.azure.com) -> Subscriptions and have at least 1 subscription listed in the table below.

If no subscription is available, create new one - Pay as you go.

Then, in VS Code - sign out, sign in and subscription will be available

Answer (score 1):

As the information explained, your logged-in Azure account doesn't seem to have associated Azure subscription.

You can login to your Azure portal, and under subscriptions, please check whether you have accessible subscription.

Comment: But my organization is currently using a paid Azure service and my account is a super-admin of it. Should I subscribe to something else?

Answer (score 1):

If vscode is complaining about not having an active subscription in the Teams Toolkit extension, for one - make sure the tenant id is added to vscode. See here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/382060/azure-vs-code-39no-subscriptions-were-found39.html and here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-how-to-find-tenant